# 一般的なリレーショナルDBは0..nと1..nを区別することは不可能？

Tags: database

### 前置き

[MySQL :: MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)
で`ER図`を書いていました。

#### 0..1と1を表現することはER図的にもリレーショナルDB的にも可能

`ER図`で`多重度`の`0..1`を示すには「`Mandatoryのチェックを外す`」ことで表現できました（厳密には`0`部分は`多重度`の`オプショナリティ`の話）。

これは`リレーショナルDB`的には「`Not Null制約（NN)をしない`」のと同義になります。

`多重度`の`1`を示すには「`Mandatoryのチェックを入れる`」「`Not Null制約（NN)付与`」で
同様に`ER図`と`リレーショナルDB`共に表現可能です。

つまり

- `オプショナルな多重度1`は`Not NUll(NN)制約なし`
- `オプショナルでない多重度1`は`Not Null(NN)制約付与`

で`リレーショナルDB`上表現可能です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 質問

#### 0..nと1..nをリレーショナルDB的に区別するには？

[MySQL :: MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)
の`ER図`では`多重度`の`0..n`と`1..n`は「`Mandatoryのチェック`」を外したり付けたりすることで表現可能です(厳密には`多重度`が`オプショナル`か`オプショナルでない`かの設定）。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一方で、`0..n`と`1..n`を`リレーショナルDB`的に表現するにはどうすればいいのか気になってしまいました（言い方を変えると`オプショナルな多重度n`と`オプショナルでない多重度n`の表現方法はどうすればいいのか気になってしまいました）。

プログラム側で（例えばRailsのバリデーション機能を使うなどで）表現することは可能だと思います。しかしDBだけでやるとするとどうなるのでしょうか？

DBだけで表現することが不可能なのであれば、`1であること`は保証できない（つまり`オプショナルではないこと`は保証できない）ので、常に`0..n`になってしまうのかと思うのですが、[MySQL :: MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)で`多重度`を書くツールのデフォルト動作は`1..n`を書くようになっているのも気になっています。

Comment: 疑問は、DB(リレーショナルDB)で、1:nの関係を表すテーブル定義方法はあるか、という内容であっていますか? (0:nについては解決しているように見受けました)

Comment: @user20098 1:nではなく1..nですね。x対yという表現をするのであれば、1:nも0:nも解決済みです。1..nを定義できれば1..nと0..nを区別できたと言えそうです(0..nは自然とこうなってしまうと考えて解決済みです）。